# Changing Terminals at Dallas Airport for a 1 hour connection

Tags: transit, layovers, short-connections, dfw

I am flying Toronto to Sydney via Dallas. My connection time at Dallas is 1 hour. The incoming flight arrives at Terminal 3 and outgoing flight leaves for Sydney from Terminal 1.

How do I go from Terminal 3 to Terminal 1? Is it far or is it walkable? My hold luggage will be checked through to Sydney at Toronto so I will have only carry on luggage at Dallas and will have no customs at Dallas (only at Sydney).

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome.  Please note that the [tag:airport-transfer] tag is for questions about getting to or from an airport by ground transportation, not for questions about changing planes at an airport.  I edited the tags for you.

Comment: Dallas/Fort Worth airport (DFW) has terminals A, B, C, D, and E. Which airport are you talking about?

Comment: Voting to close because "Dallas" can only reasonably mean Dallas-Fort Worth (DFW) in this context, and that airport doesn't have a Terminal 1 or a Terminal 3. The asker hasn't come back to clarify in four months.